# ScrollTo strange behavior

Tags: javascript, scrollto

I'm using ScrollTo plugin in my site,
I also use requirejs to load my files.

```
require(['jquery','skrollr','boodstrap','scrollto'],function($,skrollr,b,scrolltoo){....
```

When i use code:

```
$("#about").ScrollTo();
```

all is working well, but if I use:

```
$.scrollTo("#about", 800, {easing:'elasout'});
```

its not working at all.

Also i try to add offset to scroll using:

```
$.extend($.scrollTo.defaults, {
  offset: 50,
  duration: 800
});
```

Also no results.
Can any one explain me were is error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation says in ["window shorthand"](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo#window-shorthand):

> You can use $.scrollTo(...) as a shorthand for $(window).scrollTo(...).

So `$.scrollTo("#about", 800, {easing:'elasout'});` is not the same as `$("#about").ScrollTo();` (which btw, should be `scrollTo`).